# GraphQL Syntax for mapping array on mutation field

Tags: symfony, vue.js, graphql, apollo

I'm looking for advice on syntax. In my query, I need my backend (Graphlite, Symfony) to get the child items. The way I get the regular item is as below, and works correctly. I'm not well versed enough in GraphQL / Apollo / VueJS / GraphQLite to know which technology owns the "{id: $itemId}" syntax, nor do I know what it is called, so I can't find any info about it.

```
insertItem: gql` mutation insertItem(
    $itemId: Uuid!,
    $childItemIds: [Uuid!]!
) {
    insertItem(
        item: {id: $itemId},
        childItems:  { id: { in : { $childItemIds} }
    ){
       // ... stuff
    }
}`
```

So, given that the {id: $itemId} correctly works for getting an item, I assume there is some graphQL syntax that would work to apply the childItemIds to get the childItems. Is there a name for this type of mapping? What would the syntax be?

Comment: `$childItemIds` is a list of `Uuid`. I don't think that there is a way to turn it to a list of objects inside the query text. You probably have to define `childItem` object type and use `$childItemIds: [childItem!]!` as an argument. Or modify `insertItem` to accept `[Uuid!]!` and do the mapping on the server's side.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! Uuid -> Item mapping is already happening on the server side, as per the item {id: $itemId} part working (I get an "Item" object on the server side). That portion is a graphqlite https://graphqlite.thecodingmachine.io/docs/input-types setup. However, since apollo seems to happily accept the {id: $itemId} as good syntax, I'm assuming there's a way to pass the equivalent as mapping ids from an array of Uuid, which is the syntax I'm hoping to figure out.

Comment: How `insertItem` is defined in your schema?

Comment: The expected types are ItemInput! for the item, and [ItemInput!]! for the childItems. The ItemInput is a intermediary made by GraphQLite to create an Item object on the PHP backend side.

Comment: Then `$childItemIds` should be `[ItemInput!]!`. Graphql syntax doesn't allow mapping from one list to another inside of a query. `{id: $itemId}` works because it is a single item matching the shape of `ItemInput`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per discussion with @UjinT34, since this couldn't be done inline with GraphQL, I created an array of ItemInput before calling the mutation:

```
          for (var i = 0, len = item.childItems.length; i < len; i++) {
            childItems.push({ id : item.childItems[i].id } )
          }
```

The original query then became:

```
insertItem:`` gql` mutation insertItem(

    $itemId: Uuid!,
    $childItemIds: [ItemInput!]!
) {
    insertItem(
        item: {id: $itemId},
        childItems:  $childItemIds
    ){
       // ... stuff
    }
}
```

Once I understood that the `{id: $item}` wasn't a magic GQL/GraphQLite syntax and was simply an inline javascript object being created, the solution became fairly simple.